# Append ASP.Net element via jQuery .append()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, append

Is it possible to do something like this

```
$("#popupForgot").append("<asp:TextBox ID='emailTextF' runat='server' Width='200px' Text='" + $.cookie("forLogin") + "'></asp:TextBox>")
```

I need to append an asp.net element to a div tag which will have the cookie value as it's text. I've tried with the code above and it  doesn't work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can only append HTML
 controls and not ASP.NET controls using jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do this, because `asp:TextBox` is rendered via server-side, whereas jQuery works on client-side.

However you can render your textbox with `asp:TextBox` control and then you can change its value with jQuery:

```
$("#emailTextF").text($.cookie("forLogin"));
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out that `asp:TextBox` rendered id isn't equal to `id` parameter (used inside `asp:TextBox`), try this:

```
$("#<%= emailTextF.ClientID %>").text($.cookie("forLogin"));
```

Comment: Can you post html of your textbox? Did you executed your JavaScript code inside `document.ready`?

Comment: ASP will change the ID of the textbox; you either need to ensure that the generated ID is available in javascript, or set the appropriate property on the textbox to not alter the ID.

Comment: @R.App The reason that it probably didn't work is that .Net Controls often have different client side ID's than the original server side IDs. You may have to use <%=emailTextF.clientID %> to get the correct client ID at runtime

Comment: @Rondel Yeah it seems so, I've updated my answer to address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is, in the end, just JavaScript code.  Javascript code runs in the client's browser.

ASP tags are a server side construct; they will be converted into `<input type="Text"/>` fields (or something else for multi-line textboxes) before they are sent to the client's browser.

These two are completely separate concepts that can't really interact with each other (directly).

If you want to add a textbox via JQuery it can't be an ASP textbox, it needs to be an HTML textbox.  If you really do need to add an ASP textbox (you don't appear to need it from what you've shown here though) then you'll need to do a postback to the server to add it.  (You could do that postback asynchronously via AJAX if you wanted.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run in the browser, this means that you asp:TextBox will not be processed by the server.  So, in short, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, cause ASP.NET tags processed on the server-side, before data sends to the client.
The ways is:
-add this ASP.NET control before, and change it's value by JQuery, 
-if you need to add controls **dynamically**, use sample html tag , and get data on server from the Form.